# Minimal polynomial of $b$ over $k[a+b,c+d]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, minimal-polynomials, transcendence-degree

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $a,b,c,d \in k[x,y]$ be four polynomials, each two are algebraically independent over $k$.
Let $R:=k[a+b,c+d]$ be of [transcendence degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222981/transcendence-degree-for-a-k-algebra-which-is-an-integral-domain) two over $k$ 
(so $a+b,c+d,b$ are algebraically independent over $k$).

Since the transcendence degree of $k[x,y]$ is two, every three elements of $k[x,y]$ are algebraically dependent over $k$, in particular, $b,a+b,c+d$ are algebraically dependent over $k$, so $b$ is algebraic over $k[a+b,c+d]$.

> Is it possible to somehow characterize the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $k[a+b,c+d]$?

**Example:** $a=x+x^2+y^2$, $b=-2xy$, $c=x^2+y^2$, $d=y-2xy$.
Then $a+b=x+x^2+y^2-2xy=x+(x-y)^2$ and $c+d=x^2+y^2+y-2xy=y+(x-y)^2$.

What is the minimal polynomial $m_{-2xy}(T) \in k[a+b,c+d][T]$ of $-2xy$ over 
$k[a+b,c+d]=k[x+(x-y)^2,y+(x-y)^2]=k[x,y]$?
It is of course $m_{-2xy}(T)=T+2xy \in k[x,y][T]$.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: $k[a+b,c+d,b] = k[a,b,c+d]$ has transcendence degree 3.

Comment: @JakeLevinson, thank you. By assumption, $R=k[a+b,c+d]$ has transcendence degree $2$, for example, if $a,b,c,d \in k[x,y]$ then $R \subseteq k[x,y[$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson, you probably thought that $a,b,c,d$ are variables over $k$, but actually I thought of $a,b,c,d \in k[x,y]$. Please, do you have any ideas about my question?

Comment: I see. You should edit this into the question then...

Comment: ok, thank you, I will soon. Please, any ideas are welcome.